# How do I apply cv::Rect on a pointer to image?

Tags: c++, opencv

I am trying to display half of an image (from a pointer to an image):

```
#include <opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc.hpp>
#include <iostream>

void main() {

    // Load image
    std::string path = "Resources/test.png";
    cv::Mat img = cv::imread(path);
    
    // Pointer to image
    cv::Mat* img_p = new cv::Mat(img.size(), CV_8UC1);
    *img_p = img;

    // Find size of rows and columns
    int nRows = img_p->rows;
    int nCols = img_p->cols;

    // Display left half of image
    cv::imshow("left image", *img_p(cv::Rect(0, 0, nCols / 2, nRows)));
    
    cv::waitKey(5000);
    delete img_p;
}
```

I get an error on this line:

```
cv::imshow("left image", *img_p(cv::Rect(0, 0, nCols / 2, nRows)));
```

The error is:

```
expression preceding parantheses of apparent call must have (pointer-to-) function type
```

How do I access half of the image from the pointer?
**EDIT**
I want to access half of the image from the pointer for better performance.

Comment: probably `(*img_p)(cv::Rect(0, 0, nCols / 2, nRows))`should work, but please, please, please dont use pointers of cv::Mat unless you have a really good reason. cv::Mat object doesnt deep copy data and is in fact similar to a smart pointer to the actual pixel data. I doubt that you will get any visible speedup and probably your extra costs for more development time and fixing hard to find bugs and problems wont be worth it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to use new/delete or pointers for what you're trying to do.

```
void main() {

    // Load image
    std::string path = "Resources/test.png";
    cv::Mat img = cv::imread(path);
    
    cv::Mat subImg = img(cv::Rect(0, 0, img.cols / 2, img.rows));

    // Display left half of image
    cv::imshow("left image", subImg);
    
    cv::waitKey(5000);
}
```

All `cv::Mat` copies share the same data/buffer, unless you explicitly use `cv::Mat::clone()`.

Comment: Sure, but pointers are more efficient. How would you access a submatrix of an image from a pointer to the image?

Comment: Unless you're creating millions of `cv::Mat` handler copies per second in your program, no, pointers won't be any more efficient. Seeing things like `new cv::Mat(...))` it seems you have misconceptions about what OpenCV handlers do, how they work and how efficient they are.